# How to correctly use FormulaData

Tags: units, curated-data

I am exploring some of the functions involving units and formulas, and wondered how to input quantities if the variable has a subscript.

This works

```
FormulaData["NewtonsLawOfUniversalGravitation", 
 {"r" -> Quantity[12, "Meters"],
  QuantityVariable[Subscript["m", 1], "Mass"] -> 
   Quantity[12, "Kilograms"],
  QuantityVariable[Subscript["m", 2], "Mass"] -> 
   Quantity[12, "Kilograms"]
  }
 ]
```

But when I tried to evaluate using a subscripted m,  it doesn't recognize the variable.

I checked the documentation and didn't see any examples with subscripted variables.

Any help with the proper way to work with these kinds of expressions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
formula = FormulaData["NewtonsLawOfUniversalGravitation"];

formula /. {
  QuantityVariable["r", "Distance"] -> Quantity[12, "Meters"],
  QuantityVariable[Subscript["m", 1], "Mass"] -> Quantity[12, "Kilograms"],
  QuantityVariable[Subscript["m", 2], "Mass"] -> Quantity[12, "Kilograms"]}
```

> [image]